# Will paginate showing `RangeError`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem for pagination. This is my code:

```
def index
  @templates = Template.all
  @templates = Template.paginate(:page => params[:offset], :per_page => params[:limit])
end
```

`Template` has 52 records in database. When this action is executed, it shows an invalid page error. I don't understand the problem. Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: Can you please print the params hash inside your index action: `puts params.inspect`? and show us the output? Just want to make sure you receive valid `:offset` there.

Comment: Not need to fetch **all** templates and then fetch paginated templates. I would remove the `@templates = Template.all`

Comment: Template.all will return an ActiveRelation, it won't get all Templates and instantiate them.  The two lines could be combined, however.

Comment: Offset and page aren't usually the same (offset 0 is page 1).  are you sending offset=0?